# fetching data from innermost class using Retrofit. Help me to display data of classes A and B

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

1. The following is the JSON I was trying to  fetch data from. I need to
2. extract and display names and class using retrofit2.
   3.I tried several sites, but only able to fetch data directly from an array
   4.But not from an array of objects. That would be formed by this code.

   ```
        {
            "Class1" :{
                    "A": [
                { 
                 "name" : "paul",
                 "class" : "first"
                }
                        ],
                   "B": [
                {  
                  "name" : "anna",
                  "class" : "second"
                }
                       ]
                },

       "Class2" :{
                 "A": [
                        { 
                        "name" : "matthew",
                       "class" : "first"
                         }
                      ],
                 "B": [
                        {  
                        "name" : "joe",
                        "class" : "second"
                        }
                      ]
                   }
       }
   ```

Can you tell me Why I am getting into onFailure() method. What is wrong with my code

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private static final String Tag = "com.example";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bList);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    String API_BASE_URL = "xyz.com";

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging); 
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();



    ApiInterface client =  retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Example>> call = client.getdate();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //Response success. Handle data here
            }
            else{
                //For getting error message
                Log.d("Error message",response.message());
                //For getting error code. Code is integer value like 200,404 etc
                Log.d("Error code",String.valueOf(response.code()));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Example is my main class

The following is MyAPIInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {public interface ApiInterface {
          @GET("/sement")
          Call<List<Example>> getdate(@Query("date")String date);

              }
```

Comment: your json format is invalid

Comment: this is right format:  {
  "Class1": {
    "A": [
      {
        "name": "paul",
        "class": "first"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "name": "anna",
        "class": "second"
      }
    ]
  }, "Class2" : {
    "A": [
      {
        "name": "matthew",
        "class": "first"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "name": "joe",
        "class": "second"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Preeti. Regarding to your question first check your JSON response which is invalid. Also you should implement model class as per your json response.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid. But, for your question, the answer is
You have to create models using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ from JSON and after that use GSON library to map json data to models.

Refer this link you will get the idea https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

OR

For above example, you will get the name & class like

```
List<A> alist = mainclass.getClass1().getA();
for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
       String name = alist.get(i).getName();
       String class = alist.get(i).getClass();
}
```

And do same for Class B

Comment: I cannot share the true JSON, so I created a dummy JSON for reference.
I have already converted everything and created models. What I am not able to do is how to display the name and class

Comment: Well, using this example you can get the name and class like, String name = mainclass.getClass1().getA().get(i).getName(); String class = mainclass.getClass1().getA().get(i).getClass();

Comment: Class1  is generated in the below form by jsonschema2pojo.org 
public Class1 getClass1() {
            return class1;
        }

        public void setClass1(Class1 class1) {
            this.class1 = class1;
        }                                                                                                                  So, getClass1() is giving an error that "non-static method cannot be referenced through static context"

Answer (score 0):

First Validate your Json.

Use this tool for Json to  Class Objects
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Once you create Objects.

here getData() is first json object.

```
List<A> listA= response.body().getData().getClass1().getA();
List<B> listB=response.body().getData().getClass1().getB();

for(A list:listA)
list.getname();        //paul
list.getclass();       //first

for(B list:listB) 
list.getname();       // anna
list.getclass();      //second



List<A> listA= response.body().getData().getClass2().getA();
List<B> listB=response.body().getData().getClass2).getB();

for(A list:listA)
list.getname();           //matthew
list.getclass();          //first

for(B list:listB)
list.getname();           //joe
list.getclass();          //second
```

Comment: Class1 is generated in the below form by jsonschema2pojo.org public Class1 getClass1() { return class1; } public void setClass1(Class1 class1) { this.class1 = class1; } So, getClass1() is giving an error that "non-static method cannot be referenced through static context"

Comment: @Preeti `getClass1()` is an instance method, meaning you need an instance of the `Class1` class in order to call it. You're attempting to call it on the `Class1` type itself.